# display not updating python

Tags: python, pygame

```
import random  
import pygame  
from pygame.locals import *  
import sys  

class Peg:

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = Row.colors[color]
        self.num = color

    def clicked(self):
        self.num += 1
        if(self.num>5):
            self.num = 0
        self.color = Row.colors[self.num]

class Row:  
    colors = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'none']

    def __init__(self, solution):
        if(not solution):
            self.pegs = [Peg(6) for x in range(4)]
        else:
            self.pegs = [Peg(random.randint(0, 5)) for x in range(4)]

class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.rows = [Row(False) for x in range(12)]
        self.solution = Row(True)

pygame.init()

b = Board()

def draw_board(b):  
    c=0  
    for x in range(50, 600, 50):  
        screen.blit(row, (50, x))  
        for y in range(0, 4):  
            screen.blit(pegs[b.rows[(int)(x/50)].pegs[y].num], ((84+(52*y), x+1)))  
        c+=1  


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 700))  
pygame.display.set_caption('Mastermind')  

pegs = [pygame.image.load('images/peg_{}.png'.format(Row.colors[x])) for x in range(7)]  
row = pygame.image.load('images/row.png')  



draw_board(b)  
pygame.display.update()  


while True:  
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
            if event.type == QUIT:  
                pygame.quit()  
                sys.exit()  
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:  
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:  
                    pygame.quit()  
                    sys.exit()  
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  
                if(event.button==1):  
                    b.rows[0].pegs[0].clicked()  

    draw_board(b)  
    pygame.display.update()
```

can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong. after everything ids first drawn it wont update when i use the clicked function in the pegs class, i used the console and print statement to see if it was actually changing and it was. the problem is that it wont show the updated color. i know its not pygame its my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pig `0,0` is never drawn:

```
def draw_board(b):  
    c = 0
    for x in range(50, 600, 50):
        screen.blit(row, (50, x))
        for y in range(0, 4):
            screen.blit(pegs[b.rows[int(x/50)].pegs[y].num], ((84+(52*y), x+1)))
        c += 1
```

If you look at this statement : `int(x/50)` and then look at `x`, you see that `x` will always be at least `50`, so `x/50` will always be bigger than one, so the first row will not be drawn. You can fix this by doing the same as you did for y:

```
def draw_board(b):  
    c = 0
    for x in range(12):
        screen.blit(row, (50, 50 + x * 50))
        for y in range(0, 4):
            screen.blit(pegs[b.rows[x].pegs[y].num], (84 + 52 * y, 51 + x * 50))
        c += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I could not figure out what was happening.